# Merging Multiple Date and Values Pairs into One Date Column in r

Tags: r

My data column header looks like this:

Date1 Variable1 Date2 Variable 2 Date3 Variable 3 Date4 Variable4

[image: Image of data]

The length of each date/variable pair is different.

Does anyone know how to combine all the date values so that the "Date' is in one column like this:

Date Variable 1 Variable 2 Variable 3 Variable 4

Comment: Add some example data before and after your process, so it will be clear what you are trying to do. You will get a better answer this way.

Comment: It is better you show the expected output based on the example.  Please use `dput` to show the data instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this could be a fun exercise.

I mocked some of your data to a csv.

```
> raw_input <- read.csv('date variable sample.csv')
> raw_input
                 Date Variable.1           Date2 Variable.2            Date4 Variable4
1       9/12/2009         82       9/12/2009         41       15/12/2009         0
2 9/12/2009 12:00         80 9/12/2009 12:00         38 23/03/2010 16:00        71
3 9/12/2009 16:00         80 9/12/2009 16:00         42 25/03/2010 21:00        73
```

I then created a set.1, set.2 ... to separate your Date, Variable pair into different data frames.

```
> set.1 <- raw_input[c('Date','Variable.1')]
> colnames(set.1) <- c('Date', 'Variable')

             Date Variable
1       9/12/2009       82
2 9/12/2009 12:00       80
3 9/12/2009 16:00       80

> set.2 <- raw_input[c('Date2', 'Variable.2')]
> colnames(set.2) <- c('Date', 'Variable')

             Date Variable
1       9/12/2009       41
2 9/12/2009 12:00       38
3 9/12/2009 16:00       42

> set.4 <- raw_input[c('Date4', 'Variable4')]
> colnames(set.4) <- c('Date', 'Variable')

              Date Variable
1       15/12/2009        0
2 23/03/2010 16:00       71
3 25/03/2010 21:00       73
```

Then I merged all the data frames with Reduce().

```
> fin <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=T, by=c("Date")), list(set.1, set.2, set.4))
> fin
              Date Variable.x Variable.y Variable
1        9/12/2009         82         41       NA
2  9/12/2009 12:00         80         38       NA
3  9/12/2009 16:00         80         42       NA
4       15/12/2009         NA         NA        0
5 23/03/2010 16:00         NA         NA       71
6 25/03/2010 21:00         NA         NA       73
```

You can also normalize (ignore time) so you can group your dates but you probably didn't want to do this.

Happy coding!

Comment: I did the above and used `na.omit()` to remove NA in each data frame prior to using the `Reduce()` function.